# Microsoft Azure ROPC Flow 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory, cypress

So I've got some weird behaviour, when I want to use the [azure ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc).

When i test the Endpoint with [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) everything works fine. I've get the IdToken and AccessToken which I need.

As soon as i try to build the request via my own code. I get an 400 Bad Request.

I use exactly the same tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, scope, grantType, username and password.

Obviously I censored the real values.

My code with [JavaScript fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

```
 fetch('https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    redirect: 'follow',
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        client_id: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        client_secret: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        grant_type: 'password',
        password: 'secretPassword',
        scope: 'profile openid email user.read user.readbasic.all',
        username: 'user@test.com'
      })
  })
```

My code with [Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request) Request:

```
cy.request({
        url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
        method: "POST",
        body: {
          grant_type: "password",
          client_id: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
          client_secret: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
          scope: 'profile openid email user.read user.readbasic.all',
          username: 'user@test.com',
          password: 'secretPassword',
        },
        form: true,
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        //injectTokens(response.body)
    })
```

That's the Error I get, when i call the Endpoint with Code:

```
Body: {
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "AADSTS50079: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must enroll in multi-factor authentication to access '123ab123-12a1-1234-1234-abcdef123456'.\r\nTrace ID: 1234abcd-1234-1234-abcd-123412341234\r\nCorrelation ID: 12341234-1234-1234-1234-12341234a091\r\nTimestamp: 2021-07-02 12:10:51Z",
  "error_codes": [
    50079
  ],
  "timestamp": "2021-07-02 12:10:51Z",
  "trace_id": "12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234",
  "correlation_id": "1234123-1234-1234-1234-123412341234",
  "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50079",
  "suberror": "basic_action"
}
```

With [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) I get a 200 OK:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "email profile User.Read User.ReadBasic.All openid",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": "eyTooooooooooooken",
    "id_token": "eyToooooooooooken"
}
```

Comment: Are you making that request from a front-end app?

Comment: @juunas yes i make the request from inside the front-end app context

Answer (score 1):

This is because MFA is enabled for the account you're signing with. Refer to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userstates) for disabling MFA per user